# Location service calculations

Tags: java, android, geolocation

I created an application that sends every 1 min the phone location (using the GPS satellite) to my mysql db.

One location might give you diffrent result sometimes for example st. x # 5 or st. x # 2-8.
That's a problem for me because if I stay in the same location for 12 hours (while sleeping) my db will be flooded with locations that are almost the same.

My question is how I avoid that and in the whole 12 hours I will get a single location and if it possible the most accurate(less important).. maybe there is an option to check if the phone is moving?and if not to stop the tracking?

Comment: What is wrong with `if (currentSituation.equals(previousSituation)) doNothing(); else sendLocation();`

Comment: As suggested by Android developers [like this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)

Comment: If your location doesn't change just don't load it to the server.

Comment: You're going to get variance in GPS locations, which you have to compensate for (the *minDistance* approach that *gabe* suggests is a good solution). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_analysis_for_the_Global_Positioning_System for more information.

Comment: hey gabe, sorry for the edit, just to fix the link that was not showing very well.

Comment: The phone is not moving but the location I'm getting from the provider is changing as I said.

Comment: no worries. was editing it myself. ;-)

Comment: Thank you, and sorry for the stupid question what would you send as the minDistance parameter?what is the most acceptable amount of distance?

Comment: Depends on how accurate you want to track your device and how accurate the location is at the moment. But you could evaluate the accuracy of the location and set the threshold to 1,5 times the accuracy.

Comment: @gabe - why did you delete your answer? it was a good one (although maybe could have been expanded)

Comment: my post was converted to a comment... a moderator has deleted it

Comment: @gabe I want to be as accurate as possible but it cost me a price.. let's say that I send a 1 meter parameter to the requestLocationUpdate I will keep getting locations when I will move at my house and they locations might be diffrent as I said (st.x # 1, st.x #1-5 and even city y st.x) which means that my db will be flooded with many locations when my phone is at my house.. for that reason I tried to set the meter parameter to 30 meter but I failed as I said in your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Android developers [like this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)

by using min distance in the `requestLocationUpdate()` method.

To determine the min distance you could evaluate the accuracy of the last location and set the threshold to 1,5 times the accuracy.

In addition you can set a `minTime` depending on how often you want a location update. And there is a tutorial with code.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#BestEstimate

where you can determine wether the current location is better than the new location and only
then send it to the server.

Comment: Thanks for that but there is something I don't understand, I send to the requestLocationUpdate a 30meter parameter and I keep getting locations when my phone is not moving.. how come?

Comment: It could be that the gps is not very accurate, indoor is a problem for sure. What location provider are you using? Network or Gps? Its kind of hard to help without seeing the code.

Comment: The code is tone of lines so I will sum it up by saying GPS :) I don't use the network providor since it gives a very not accurate location but sometimes(mostly indoor) the gps can't generate a location so I'm thinking about adding the network providor.. and yes it was tested indoor.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer your question from the database perspective.

You should only insert the database if there is any changes to database since the last interval.

For example, on the night before you sleep, you send x1, y1 to the database with timestamp, t1. You will keep sending x1, y1 to database from t2, t3, t4. You can just discard it from the database. Once you start moving, you will insert x2, y2 at t1000.

In the database, there is only two records for t1 and t1000.

If you want to know the location of t10, then you should just get results from t1.